# How to plot this type of graph (errorbar)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r'https://exploratory.io/data/kanaugust/2016-California-Election-Data-oTv4Hgd1UT/2016%20California%20Election%20Data.csv')

df['cluster'] = [3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1]

df = df.drop(columns=['COUNTY_NAME', 'PARTY_NAME']).groupby('cluster').agg(['mean', 'std'])
df
```

[image]

I would like to make graph of it, like this one:

[image]

For each cluster every line is drawn as line that connects three dots.
In the middle is column mean, lower dot is mean - std, and upper mean + std.
For example for Ban on Single-use Plastic Bags and cluster 3, lower dot is 0.647902 - 0.065703, dot in the middle is 0.647902, and upper dot is 0.647902 + 0.065703.

On each x position all three clusters should be drawn, each in different color.

matplotlib errorbar could be good for that purpose, but I don't know how to use it to produce the graph as I shown above.
Maybe seaborn is good as well?

How to draw this kind of graph?

Comment: matplotlib has one of the best documentation resources I've seen. A quick look into it gives for example this https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/errorbar_limits.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-errorbar-limits-py so you can try.

Comment: I still don't know how to draw it for each multiindex column.

Comment: do you know how to draw it if your columns aren't multi-indexed?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so with [errorbar](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html):

```
df = df.drop(columns=['COUNTY_NAME', 'PARTY_NAME']).groupby('cluster').agg(['mean', 'std'])

# change categories to index
new_df = df.T.unstack()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(16,10))
for i in range(1,4):
    ax.errorbar(range(len(new_df)), new_df[new_df.columns[2*i-2]],
                yerr=new_df[new_df.columns[2*i-1]], fmt='x', 
                label=f'Cluster {i}')

ax.set_xticks(range(len(new_df)))
ax.set_xticklabels(new_df.index)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output is not perfect, but I leave the detail to you:

[image]

Comment: This is it. Thank you very much.